# How to get the public key from a certificate in windows system certstore

Tags: c++, windows, cryptoapi, certificate-store

I have added a certificate to the system store with something like this:

```
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext;
HCERTSTORE hCertStore;
CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO provInfo;

if (pCertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(MY_ENCODING_TYPE, certDER, certSize)) {
    provInfo.pwszContainerName = idCert;
    provInfo.pwszProvName = provName;
    provInfo.dwProvType = provType;
    provInfo.dwFlags = 0;
    provInfo.cProvParam = 0;
    provInfo.rgProvParam = NULL;
    provInfo.dwKeySpec = AT_SIGNATURE;

    if (!CertSetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, 0, &provInfo)) Error(TEXT("CertSetCertificateContextProperty"));

    if (!(hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, L"MY"))) Error(TEXT("CertOpenSystemStore"));
    if (!CertAddCertificateContextToStore(hCertStore, pCertContext, CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING, NULL)) Error(TEXT("CertAddCertificateContextToStore"));
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
} else Error(TEXT("CertCreateCertificateContext"));
```

Now I'm making a Cryptographyc Service Provider and need to get the public key from this certificate to implement the CPExportKey() function.

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Also, if someone could point me at a kind of guide, or howto, of CSP drivers implementation it would be great! I'm having a bad time searching documentation for these things.

Comment: Also see [Get RSA public key from CRYPT_BIT_BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23864214/608639). (The WinHTTP part does not matter for the question and answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the solution below. With all non-essential for understanding code omitted.

Iterate through the certificates in the store and through its properties to find my certificate, then use the `CryptDecodeObjectEx()` function to convert the key to the `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` format.

The key is kept at this location `pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData` and its size at `pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData`.

```
HCERTSTORE hCertStore = NULL;
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
PBYTE pbPKEY = NULL;
DWORD iPKEYSize;

hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, L"MY");

while(pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
    hCertStore,
    pCertContext))
{
    DWORD dwPropId = 0;
    while(dwPropId = CertEnumCertificateContextProperties(
        pCertContext, // The context whose properties are to be listed.
        dwPropId))    // Number of the last property found.  
    {
        // ...
        // here I compare the properties to see if it is the certificate that I want.
        // ...
        CryptDecodeObjectEx((PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING), 
            RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, 
            pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData, 
            pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData, 
            CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 
            NULL, 
            &pbPKEY, 
            &iPKEYSize);

            // pbData and pcbDataLen are output parameters of the function
            *pcbDataLen = iPKEYSize;
            memcpy(pbData, pbPKEY, *pcbDataLen);
            LocalFree((HANDLE)pbPKEY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I adapted the code you posted, but when I dump the memory at `pbPKEY` it does not look anything like the Public Key shown for the certificate when displaying it in CertMgr.msc.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @NeilWeicher What is the format in which CertMgr.msc display the Public Key? `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` is a binary blob format.

Comment: The PK in CertMgr is 140 bytes and begins like this: `30 81 89 02 81 81 00 E2 84 F5 B5 F2 28 15 AE FE`. The blob is 150 bytes and begins like this: `06 02 00 00 00 A4 00 00 52 53 41 31 00 04 00 00`. The bytes in the PK do not match any sequence in the blob. I assume i have to convert the blob in some way to get the "real" PK?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the blob is 148 bytes.

Comment: @NeilWeicher The PK in CertMgr looks like it is in an ASN encoding. To make the `pbKey` it is reversed, a header added to it, etc. I think that if you dump the `pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData` it should be equal to the value CertMgr shows. I'm curious now.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of the reversed bytes too, but that still didn't match in any way.