How to extract public key programmatically using win32 for a certificate stored in certificate store
I have imported a crt file to Personal Certificates in Local Computer. 
I can extract the same public key using base 64 encoded X509 .CER option using MMC.
My goal is to programmatically get this information using win32 apis.
So far I have tried below but the data stored in base64Cert does not match the public key.
Any ideas on what I can try to get the correct data ?
HCERTSTORE hCertStore;
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;


if (!(hCertStore = CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
    MY_ENCODING_TYPE,
    NULL,
    CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    L"MY")))
{
    std::cout<<"The MY system store did not open."<< std::endl;
}



while (pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
    hCertStore,
    pCertContext))
{
    LPTSTR pszString;
    LPTSTR pszName;
    DWORD cbSize;
    CERT_BLOB blobEncodedName;

    PBYTE pbPKEY = NULL;
    DWORD iPKEYSize;



    bool ret = CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB,
        pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData,
        pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData,
        CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG,
        NULL,
        &pbPKEY,
        &iPKEYSize);

    CERT_CONTEXT certcontext;
    certcontext.pbCertEncoded = pbPKEY;
    certcontext.cbCertEncoded = iPKEYSize;

    DWORD dwData;
    if (!CryptBinaryToStringA(certcontext.pbCertEncoded, certcontext.cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, nullptr, &dwData))
    {
        std::cout << "error \n";
    }
    std::string base64Cert(dwData, '\0');
    CryptBinaryToStringA(certcontext.pbCertEncoded, certcontext.cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, &base64Cert[0], &dwData);
    
    std::cout << base64Cert << "\n";
    
}



According to RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, The CryptExportKey function outputs the above pvStructInfo value for a dwBlobType of PUBLICKEYBLOB. The CryptImportKey function expects the above pvStructInfo value when importing a public key. Have you tried CryptImportKey?

You're encoding the key to base64 so it's not going to match what's shown in the dialog which is hex. Use CRYPT_STRING_HEX instead of CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER.

@Luke I tried and it does not give correct data.

you need not decode pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey but encode pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo
template <typename T> 
T HR(HRESULT& hr, T t)
{
    hr = t ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    return t;
}

HRESULT mm(PCSTR psz)
{
    ULONG cch = (ULONG)strlen(psz);
    if (cch > 32*2)
    {
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    CRYPT_HASH_BLOB hash {};

    HRESULT hr;

    while(HR(hr, CryptStringToBinaryA(psz, cch, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, hash.pbData, &hash.cbData, 0, 0)))
    {
        if (hash.pbData)
        {
            if (HCERTSTORE hCertStore = HR(hr, CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, 
                CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG|CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG|CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"My")))
            {
                PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = HR(hr, CertFindCertificateInStore(hCertStore, 0, 0, CERT_FIND_HASH, &hash, 0));
                
                CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);

                if (pCertContext)
                {
                    PBYTE pb = 0;
                    ULONG cb = 0;

                    if (HR(hr, CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, 
                        &pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo, 
                        CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG|CRYPT_ENCODE_NO_SIGNATURE_BYTE_REVERSAL_FLAG, 0, &pb, &cb)))
                    {
                        cch = 0, psz = 0;
                        PSTR buf = 0;
                        int len = 0;

                        static const char _____[] = "-----";
                        static const char PUBLIC_KEY[] = " PUBLIC KEY";
                        static const char BEGIN[] = "BEGIN";
                        static const char END[] = "END";
                        static const char fmt[] = "%s%s%s%s\r\n";

#define LEN_OF(s) (_countof(s) - 1)

                        enum {
                            cch_prefix = LEN_OF(_____)*2 + LEN_OF(PUBLIC_KEY) + LEN_OF(BEGIN) + 2,
                            cch_suffix = LEN_OF(_____)*2 + LEN_OF(PUBLIC_KEY) + LEN_OF(END) + 2
                        };

                        while (HR(hr, CryptBinaryToStringA(pb, cb, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, const_cast<PSTR>(psz), &cch)))
                        {
                            if (psz)
                            {
                                cch += len;

                                if (0 < (len = sprintf_s(buf + cch, cch_suffix + 1, fmt, _____, END, PUBLIC_KEY, _____)))
                                {
                                    cch += len;

                                    do 
                                    {
                                        len = min(0x80, cch);
                                        DbgPrint("%.*s", len, buf);

                                    } while (buf += len, cch -= len);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    hr = ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                                }

                                break;
                            }

                            buf = (PSTR)alloca(cch + cch_suffix + cch_prefix);

                            len = sprintf_s(buf, cch_prefix + 1, fmt, _____, BEGIN, PUBLIC_KEY, _____);

                            if (0 >= len)
                            {
                                hr = ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                                break;
                            }

                            psz = buf + len;
                        }

                        LocalFree(pb);
                    }

                    CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        hash.pbData = (PBYTE)alloca(hash.cbData);
    }

    return hr;
}


Thanks for the snippet. I am new to this topic and wondering what needs to be sent as "psz" when calling mm method.

Also, I was looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151904/how-to-get-the-public-key-from-a-certificate-in-windows-system-certstore to extract public key which is already imported in Certificate Store.

@Ariel - and wondering what needs to be sent as "psz" when calling mm method. - in concrete case Thumbprint and in your case it is "7f2a122e175db6002e69aa65e..." this is only demo way for find your cert in store. really you can use any way

@Ariel I was looking at this.. - and so what ? you need in what form publickey ? you can import it by CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2 and ? you need determinate with format of final result

I would like to get the public key in the same format using win32 apis similar to what we can get using MMC by clicking  Details of certificate -> PublicKey ->Click on "copy to file"-> select "Base 64 encoded X.509 (.CER) "  I have attached another screenshot to the post. Thanks!

@Ariel - this is not answer. mmc export certificate, not public key. i show example how export public key (not certificate) in pem format, compatible with openssl. however if you need use this programatically - best way - use single api call CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2 - so what you realy need ?
