How to Decrypt Public Key using CryptDecodeObjectEx function
I am having an issue with the CryptDecodeObjectEx function on a X509 certificate,  using the RSA algorithm "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1". I retrieve 276 BYTEs and convert it to a string of chars, of hexadecimal digits separated by spaces. i.e. ...5d a4 7b f6 4a 35...
The result is 6 BYTEs longer (18 chars) than the public key displayed in cert manager,
and the digits do not resemble the public key displayed in cert manager.
BOOL ByteToStr(DWORD cb, void* pv, LPSTR sz,int* size_sz,BOOL addSpaces,BOOL upperCaseHexDigits)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Parameters passed are:
//    pv -- the Array of BYTES to be converted.
//    cb -- the number of BYTEs in the array.
//    sz -- a pointer to the string to be returned.

{
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Declare and initialize local variables.

  BYTE* pb = (BYTE*)pv;  // local pointer to a BYTE in the BYTE array
  DWORD i;               // local loop counter
  int b;                 // local variable
  int outCharCount = 0;

  //LPSTR psz = (char*)malloc((cb * 3 + 1) * sizeof(char));

  //  Ensure that sz is large enough to hold pv.
  if (strlen(sz) < cb) {
    MyHandleError(L"The array of bytes is too long for the "
                  "allocated string.");
  }

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Begin processing loop.

  for (i = 0; i < cb; i++) {
    b = (*pb & 0xF0) >> 4;
    if (upperCaseHexDigits == TRUE)
    {
      *sz++ = (b <= 9) ? b + '0' : (b - 10) + 'A';
    }
    else
    {
      *sz++ = (b <= 9) ? b + '0' : (b - 10) + 'a';
    }
    
    outCharCount++;
    //outCharCount = outCharCount+((b <= 9) ? 1 : 2);
    b = *pb & 0x0F;
    if (upperCaseHexDigits == TRUE)
    {
      *sz++ = (b <= 9) ? b + '0' : (b - 10) + 'A';
    }
    else
    {
      *sz++ = (b <= 9) ? b + '0' : (b - 10) + 'a';
    }
    
    outCharCount++;
    //outCharCount = outCharCount + ((b <= 9) ? 1 : 2);
    pb++;
    if (addSpaces)
    {
      *sz++ = ' ';
      outCharCount++;
    }
  }
  *sz++ = 0;
  outCharCount++;
  *size_sz = outCharCount;

  return TRUE;
}  // end of ByteToStr

// Decrypt the public key
publicKeyInfo = pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo;

PBYTE pbPKEY = NULL;
//PBYTE pbPKEYdata = NULL;
DWORD iPKEYSize=0;

CryptDecodeObjectEx(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING  ,//(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING),
    RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData,
    pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData,
    CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG,//The called decoding function allocates memory for the decoded structure. A pointer to the allocated structure is returned in pvStructInfo.
    NULL,//If CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG then pDecodePara is set to NULL, then LocalAlloc and LocalFree are used to allocate and free memory
    &pbPKEY, //This parameter can be NULL to retrieve the size of this information for memory allocation purposes
    &iPKEYSize);


  LPSTR sz = (char*)malloc((iPKEYSize * 3 + 1) * sizeof(char));
  int size_sz = 0;
  BOOL succes=ByteToStr(iPKEYSize, pbPKEY, sz, &size_sz, TRUE, FALSE);  

  free(sz);
  LocalFree((HANDLE)pbPKEY);


CertGetPublicKeyLength function returns length of 2048  /8 = 256

What you are trying to do makes no sense to me. The purpose of this function is to convert ASN.1-encoded byte array to a structure. What is the point of converting the structure into a byte array? Your pbPKEY is a pointer to a structure, that contains public key, not to raw public key.

perhaps your confusion points to the answer.
“If the dwFlags CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG is set, pvStructInfo is not a pointer to a buffer but is the address of a pointer
to the buffer. Because memory is allocated inside the function and the pointer is stored at *pvStructInfo, pvStructInfo”
…perhaps I am converting the *pvStructInfo bytes to a string and not the bytes it points to?????

CryptDecodeObjectEx returns a byte array in pbPKEY and it's length in iPKEYSize.
iPKEYSize returns a length of 276 which I expected to be 256.
I then call the function ByteToStr to convert the byte array into an array of strings.
The point, or what I'm trying to do is produce the same text I see in certificate manager

"Your pbPKEY is a pointer to a structure," - what is the structure definition??? does it have a pointer to a byte array???

Structure is the way how data is stored in memory. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the end.

Your confusion was on the spot.

Your confusion was on the spot.
The public byte array doesn't need conversion its in
pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData //Public key byte array
pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData //Public key byte array size
so I just need to ByteToStr pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData

I started from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151904/how-to-get-the-public-key-from-a-certificate-in-windows-system-certstore/55190427#55190427
"How to get the public key from a certificate in windows system certstore"

...so I'm confused by the "How to get the public key from a certificate in windows system certstore" post
but have taken a step forward - thanks for your confusion/ pointing to mine

should I delete this question? the public key didn't need to be Decrypted to display it as certificate manager displays it
